# How to convert eli5.show_weights to an array/list in python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, permutation, logistic-regression

I am have trained model and everything works fine. And I am calculating the permutation importance of each feature weight. I am using the `eli5.show_weights()`  but it show the output as an `html`, but I need it to convert to some kind of a list or an array so I can access the values.

here's my code sample, excluding the `estimator's` code part to make it simple:

```
import eli5
from eli5.sklearn import PermutationImportance

perm = PermutationImportance(estimator, random_state=1).fit(X_testdf, y_testdf)
eli5.show_weights(perm, feature_names = X_testdf.columns.tolist())
```

This works fine, but I need to get the values output by `eli5.show_weights(..)` to an array or any variable so I can access these values.

I also tried, but no luck

```
np.array(eli5.show_weights(perm, feature_names=X.columns.tolist()))
```

**Can someone please help me?**

Answer (score 4):

The weights or feature importances are stored in the permutation object, such that you can extract them directly:

```
perm.feature_importances_
```

For example this could return an array like

```
array([0.   , 0.008, 0.584, 0.172]) # Only the mean, not the Std.Dev.
```

If you need them along with the feature names, you can zip the names and the feature importances:

```
 list(zip(X_test.columns.tolist(), perm.feature_importances_))
```

Alternatively, you can also convert the HTML display back into raw HTML, and then read it with Pandas. Example:

```
w = eli5.show_weights(perm, feature_names=feature_names)
result = pd.read_html(w.data)[0]
result
```

(example of output with the `iris` dataset)

```
Weight          Feature
0.5840 ± 0.1170 petal_length
0.1720 ± 0.0697 petal_width
0.0080 ± 0.0196 sepal_width
0 ± 0.0000      sepal_length
```

Although note that the `Weight` column here is a string, so you'll have to do some further manipulation.

Comment: If it's a string, how does one set the precision?

Answer (score 2):

I refer to tania's post and get list with following code .

```
result = [(x[0], x[1], x[2]) for x in zip(perm_import.feature_importances_, perm_import.feature_importances_std_, X_train.columns)]
result.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)

print(result)
```